# ng2-validation combined US/Canada Phone Validation?

Tags: angular, libphonenumber

I am using [ng2-validation](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation) which uses [libphonenumber-js](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js) to validate phone numbers. I would like to allow both US and Canadian phone numbers in a phone number form control. I am currently passing `CustomValidators.phone('US')` as the form control validator, which allows US phone numbers but disallows Canadian phone numbers.

Is there a way to allow both US and Canadian phone numbers in the form control with this validation method?

Comment: I believe the answer in that questions should solve this for you even though it is being asked with slightly different details- if not, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks @OneLunchMan but I was unable to find a solution using that thread.

Comment: Ah, you're right, my apologies! I'll add an answer to hopefully help out-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation/blob/master/src/phone/validator.ts) from the validator function you're using:

```
export const phone = (country: string): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    if (isPresent(Validators.required(control))) return null;

    let v: string = control.value;

    return isValidNumber({phone: v, country}) ? null : {phone: true};
  };
};
```

You should be able to combine these on your own with an or (something along the lines of this):

```
export const phone = (countries: string[]): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
    if (isPresent(Validators.required(control))) return null;

    let v: string = control.value;

    const validPhone: boolean = countries.map(c => isValidNumber({phone: v, c}).some(z => z);

    return validPhone ? null : {phone: true};
  };
};
```

Then inside of your validator, you can pass a list of country codes:

```
phone('US', 'CAN')
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new file `customPhoneValidator.ts` containing the following:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { isValidNumber, NationalNumber, CountryCode } from 'libphonenumber-js';

export const customPhoneValidator = (countries: CountryCode[]): ValidatorFn => {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } => {
        let v: NationalNumber = control.value;

        if (!v || v === '') return null;

        const validPhone: boolean = countries.map(c => isValidNumber(v, c)).some(z => z);

        return validPhone ? null : { phone: true };
    };
};
```

In the component which uses the validator, I declared `const customPhoneCountries: CountryCode[] = ['US', 'CA'];` and passed `customPhoneValidator(customPhoneCountries)` as a validator for the form control.