# How to use both validators for domestic and international phone number in angular

Tags: html, angular

i used the below code as a TS file, always the first argument works before the "||". Only the regex must be manipulated.

```
phoneNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(('^[0]{1}[1-9]{9}$')||('^\\+[0-9]{2,3}[0-9]{9}$'))]]
```

and the html looks like this

```
 <div>
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input formControlName="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control">
                <small>e.g. +251912121212, 0912121212</small>
                <div *ngIf="phoneNumber.invalid && (phoneNumber.dirty || phoneNumber.touched)">
                    <small *ngIf="preferenceList.hasError('required',['phoneNumber'])" style="color : red !important;"
                        class="form-text text-muted">this
                        field is required
                    </small>
                    <small *ngIf="preferenceList.hasError('pattern',['phoneNumber'])" style="color : red !important;"
                        class="form-text text-muted">Phone
                        number is not valid yet
                    </small>                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

How do I use both on the same field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng2-validation combined US/Canada Phone Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676826/ng2-validation-combined-us-canada-phone-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference I manipulated the regex in the TS file which worked fine as below!

```
phoneNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^\\+?[0-9]{3}[0-9]{9}$|[0]{1}[0-9]{9}$')]],
```